# Selenium (python) issues with Schwab, can't login to Schwab

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, stock

I've tried multiple ways of trying to login, but I have no idea why it's not working. I've tried xpath, ccs, and by Id, but nothing works. I'm fairly new to selenium, so I could be missing something important.

I tried using other people's python codes in selenium, but they were outdated, and I tried to fix them, and they still didn't work. I wonder if selenium works for Schwab at all.

(I changed the username and password inputs, obviously, but still wouldn't input anything)

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/nn/login/mobile-login.html&lang=en'
username = "Username"
password = "Password"

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

time.sleep(3)

driver.get(LOGIN_URL)
#driver.switch_to.frame('mobile-login')
username = driver.find_element('LoginId')
password = driver.find_element('Password')
username.send_keys(username)
password.send_keys(password)
driver.find_element('RememberLoginId').click()
driver.find_element('Submit').click()











#username_entry = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="LoginId"]')
#username_entry.send_keys(username)

#password_entry = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Password"]')
#password_entry.send_keys(password)

#login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginSubmitBtn"]')
#login_button.click()

time.sleep(5)
print(driver.current_url)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: do you have any Errors ?

Comment: Chances are Schwab's anti-bot mechanisms are working. According to Schwab's [robots.txt](https://www.schwab.com/robots.txt) file, the url `/public/schwab/nn/login` is not meant to be accessed by bots, and therefore they will do their best to stop you. You can still try though, so good luck, have fun! See this article: https://hackernoon.com/the-web-scraping-anti-detect-anti-bot-matrix-a-guide

Comment: @TheTridentGuy If I can't access the Xpath, CCS, or the ID doesn't that eliminate selenium?

Comment: Can you see the Chrome window? Is the script inputting the information? If not it's probably an error, but if it is it's the anti-bot measures fighting you.

Comment: @TheTridentGuy can see the chrome window, but that's it. No inputs and then the code ends. I think it could be anti-bot measures fighting me, but I've seen other people in the past (recently) do it, so I wonder if I'm not doing it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first have to switch to the iframe element then     `driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'lmsSecondaryLogin'))`

Also the locators were incorrect

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/nn/login/mobile-login.html&lang=en'
username = "Username"
password = "Password"

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

time.sleep(3)

driver.get(LOGIN_URL)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'lmsSecondaryLogin'))
userName = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'loginIdInput')
passWord = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'passwordInput')
userName.send_keys("username")
passWord.send_keys("password")
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'remember-me-checkbox-stack').click()
input("Enter any key")

# Wait until the element is clickable
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'btnLogin')))
element.click()


print(driver.current_url)
```

Manually Click Login

```
# Manually Click login
input("Enter any key")
```

Comment: I implemented some sleep commands, because I wonder if it's going too fast. It inputs the correct username and password, but it still didn't log in. I then tried only having it input the username and password and then manually clicking login, and it worked. Is there a way in selenium to have it manually input username and password, and then I click login, but then it goes back to automating in schwab?

Comment: I have added a Web driver wait for Login button to be clickable, Also if you want to click Manually on login button (not suggested) you can replace the  login button click with above `input("Enter any key") ` , you can click on the login button then enter any key in console and it will proceed with automation again